# A quick, easy way to send an email from anywhere, via hotkey, without opening Mail.app

Tags: macos, email

I am looking for an app which lives in my menu bar and, with a global hotkey, lets me bring up a window to send an email message, but which *does not* require me to have/wait for Mail.app or another application to open.

Thoughts?  [Captio](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/captio-email-yourself-1-tap/id370899391?mt=8) is great on the iPhone, and I'd like a similar flow on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I have [**MailTab for Gmail**](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mailtab-pro-for-gmail/id430252530?mt=12) (Pro version linked, there is also an ad-supported free version) which has a custom keyboard shortcut option available. There also is a flavor for **Outlook** by the same developer.

To take it a step further, Using [**BetterTouchTool (BTT)**](http://www.boastr.de), one can set a specific gesture on the touchpad to invoke a keyboard shortcut. BTT also allows for additional actions to take place, such as "Send shortcut to specific app", after performing a gesture (or even a keyboard shortcut). So the flow is:

- Double tap lower right corner

  - BTT invokes shortcut for MailTab (Default is `ctrl + g`)
  - BTT sends the shortcut `c` to MailTab

    - Note: `c` is the shortcut for compose in the web view for GMail. For more keyboard shortcuts for gmail type `?` while at your inbox for a comprehensive list.
- Profit

All this happens when I double tap the lower right corner. I tried to eliminate the need for sending a shortcut to bring the inbox into view by calling on the app itself via BTT, but it doesn't want to play nice.